# Objective-C - method not in documentation but can be called

Tags: objective-c

I was learning objective-c and found that I could call some methods of NSObject, but can't find them in the documentation. Such as the method valueForKey

```
NSObject *obj = [[NSObject alloc]init];
NSLog(@"%@", [obj valueForKey:@"class"]);
```

will print the class name. 
However NSObject seems not have method valueForKey
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html

Actually the protocal NSKeyValueCoding has that method but it seems the NSObject conforms only to NSObject protocal.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSObject has a category that adds these methods:

```
@interface NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding)
```

Open xcode, press cmd + shft + o -- search for NSKeyValueCoding.h -- open it and see .

Comment: Or just command-click while hovering over `valueForKey` and it will show you a list of definitions for that method.

Answer (score 0):

`NSKeyValueCoding` appears to be an informal protocol, implemented by means of a category on `NSObject` and as such will not be part of the reference page of `NSObject`.